# Control not immediately updating bound property with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have controls which are not updating their bound object's respective properties until focus is lost.  There are similar questions with accepted answers referencing `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChange` being declared, which I do, yet the behavior persists.  Here's an example implementation.  I'll try to be thorough, yet concise.  The `MyConfig` class is accessed through a property in a Singleton class I call `Configuration`.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyConfig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Foo,
        Bar
    }

    public MyConfig()
    {
        MyProperty = MyEnum.Foo;
    }

    private MyEnum _MyProperty;
    public MyEnum MyProperty
    {
        get { return _MyProperty; }
        set { if (value != _MyProperty) { _MyProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); } }
    }

    [field: NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(propertyName);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public partial class ConfigForm : Form
{
    public ConfigForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyComboBox.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyConfig.MyEnum)));
    }

    private void ConfigForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyComboBox.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyConfig.MyEnum));
        MyComboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", Configuration.Instance.MyConfig, "MyProperty", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, given the following brief implementation, what I could be overlooking to ensure immediate property changes.  I can change, in this case from `Foo` to `Bar` in the ComboBox, but unless I remove focus from the ComboBox, nothing changes.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The WinForms `ComboBox` is wonky with regards to `OnPropertyChanged`. Here's some code from an old project that I used to get `OnPropertyChanged` working the way I expect for the `SelectedItem` property. This works for my specific instance, but I usually struggle to get this scenario working sometimes. Good luck!

```
/// <summary>
/// A modification of the standard <see cref="ComboBox"/> in which a data binding
/// on the SelectedItem property with the update mode set to DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
/// actually updates when a selection is made in the combobox.
/// </summary>
public class BindableComboBox : ComboBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e);

        var bindings = this.DataBindings
            .Cast<Binding>()
            .Where(x => 
                x.PropertyName == "SelectedItem" && 
                x.DataSourceUpdateMode == DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        foreach (var binding in bindings)
        {
            // Force the binding to update from the new SelectedItem
            binding.WriteValue();

            // Force the Textbox to update from the binding
            binding.ReadValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks a million!  And you've taught me a bit about customizing existing controls :)

Comment: This is the only solution that I've found that really works. Thank You.

Comment: I used this as a fix for when the combo box drop down was being selected by mouse and the bound data was not being updated/changing but did on second try.  In my instance  I changed it to the SelectedValue property..  So far it seems to work.  The Online Telerik converter (https://converter.telerik.com/) also converts the above code into VB successfully in case anyone needs to know how.  Thanks for this Nicholas - Combo boxes are a nightmare to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

@Nicholas Piasecki deserves credit for leading me to my solution so, unless you couldn't arrive at a solution based on his answer, please vote for his answer.

---

There were three main changes that I had to make for this fix to work in my situation.

- I was trying to access the property on the object bound to the SelectedValue property of the ComboBox.  Therefore, I had to include the "SelectedValue" property name in the Linq where clause.
- If you're setting the databinding via the form designer in Visual Studio, 
  and simply set what the SelectedValue or SelectedItem is bound to, the default 
  datasource update mode is "OnValidation".  You can see this if you go to the 
  "(Advanced)" settings for the databinding on the ComboBox.
  So, you have to include that datasource update mode as well if that's what you're using.
- In my case I also had to raise the OnSelectionChangeCommitted event *after* looping through the bindings and doing the Write/ReadValue calls.  Since I was subscribing to SelectionChangeCommitted event of the ComboBox on the form, calling base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted before looping through the bindings and forcing them to update caused the bound object's property to still not be set.

So, here's my version of @Nicholas Piasecki's answer (also converted to VB.NET):

```
''' <summary>
''' Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted"/> event _after_ forcing any data bindings to be updated.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="e">An <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e As EventArgs)
    Dim bindings As List(Of Binding) = ( _
        From x In Me.DataBindings.Cast(Of Binding)()
        Where (x.PropertyName = "SelectedItem" OrElse x.PropertyName = "SelectedValue" OrElse x.PropertyName = "SelectedIndex") AndAlso
              (x.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged OrElse x.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)
    ).ToList()

    For Each b As Binding In bindings
        ' Force the binding to update from the new SelectedItem
        b.WriteValue()
        ' Force the Textbox to update from the binding
        b.ReadValue()
    Next

    MyBase.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I had, as above, also put the MyBase.OnSelectionChangeCommitted at the end and added the SelectcedValue.